# Why repeatForever is not working in spritekit, swift3

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, sprite

This is my code for test:

```
    let cloud1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cloud1")
    cloud1.position = CGPoint(x: size.width + cloud1.size.width/2, y: size.height / 2)
    addChild(cloud1)
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.25)

    let actionMove = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: -cloud1.size.width/2, y: cloud1.position.y), duration: 2.0)

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([actionMove, wait])

    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)
    cloud1.run(repeatAction)
```

This cloud is only run one time, please tell me the solution please

Comment: Once you have moved to `CGPoint(x: -cloud1.size.width/2, y: cloud1.position.y)`, where further are you expecting to move to?

Comment: i just want it move again from middle left to right. any idea

Comment: What would make it do that? I don't see any action in your sequence that does that. You tell it to move left and that's _all_ you tell it to do.

Comment: I tell it move left, and wait 5 second and want it move left again , and again .. what whould I code? Thanks

Comment: Use `move(by:)`, not `move(to:)`.

Answer (score 4):

based on your question, I think I might have a solution.

the reason as to why it is not moving after it reaches a certain destination is because you are using `moveTo`. Here is a little example I made based on the code you have provided.

```
var cloudSpeed = CGFloat(12) //this can be any number you want, the higher the faster


    let cloud1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cloud1")
    cloud1.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height / 2)
    addChild(cloud1)
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.25)

    let actionMove = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx:-10 * ballSpeed, dy:0), duration: 1) //experiment with the dx value. If you want the cloud to travel from right to left make it a negative

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([actionMove, wait])

    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)
    cloud1.run(repeatAction)
```

hopefully this solves your problem!